# Center div inside image with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to center a div inside an image with flexbox (I only want flexbox), but since img does not have closing tag, I cannot make it work. How to do?

```css
.uno {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="uno">
   <img src="https://www.placecage.com/300/300" alt="">
   <h1>Center this text</h1>
</div>
```

This puts my text in the center but to the right of the img. Only flexbox solutions.

Comment: Are you trying to place text on top of the image?

Comment: If you give the image as background. it will be easy to align the text to center

Comment: @KPranavRam - no, in center horizontally and vertically

Comment: @DanielprabhakaranN - i know, but i cannot. it is like this presented here.

Comment: Div inside an img, hm interesting...

Comment: _center a div inside an image_ - what do you mean by that? Are you trying to place the `h1` element over the image and have the text centered vertically and horizontally?

Comment: @Yousaf - yesss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place the text over the image , give absolute position to `h1` element and add position relative on the container element.

Since you have set `justify-content` and `align-items` properties on the flex container to `center`, when text is placed over the image, it will be centered horizontally and vertically.

```css
.uno {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="uno">
  <img src="https://www.placecage.com/300/300" alt="" />
  <h1>
    Center this text
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't place other elements inside an `img` tag. As others have said, it would make more sense to use a `background-image` but I'm guessing there's a reason you need it like this.

For how you want it you'd have to set the image to `position: absolute; z-index: 0;` and the `h1` to `z-index: 1;`, also, the height of `.uno` would need to be reset otherwise it could clip off the edges of the page.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.uno {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

h1 {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="uno">
  <img src="https://www.placecage.com/300/300" alt="" />
  <h1>
    Center this text
  </h1>
</div>
```

Love the image btw.